# Getting an error when trying to use the <= operator for two variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to ask the user to enter a list of prices for some items and determine how many of those items they can buy with a user inputted dollar amount. However when i try to create a loop to print how many options or combinations they have i get an error saying i cannot compare a float and a list.

```
prices = input("enter a list of prices: ").split()
[float(x) for x in prices]
dollar = float(input("enter dollar amount: "))
print()
options = 0
if prices <= dollar:
    options += 1 
    print(f"you have {options} options")
```

I thought since i was converting the inputs of the lists to a float i'd have no problem using a comparison operator and I'm unsure what i need to do to fix it.

Comment: Simply because `prices` is a _list_ of _what-you-thought-as_ `float`'s. What's your expected output anyway?

Comment: Your list comprehension does not do anything. You will have to store the result somewhere.

Comment: @CodeRed It's a list of strings since it is never changed.

Comment: @KlausD. that's why I added _"what-you-thought-as"_

Comment: Try `prices = [float(x) for x in input().split()]; dollar = float(input()); print(sum(1 for x in prices if x <= dollar))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
prices = [float(x) for x in input("Prices: ").split()]
dollar = float(input("Dollar: "))
options = sum(1 for x in prices if x <= dollar)
print(f"Options: {options}")
```

Notice that we must:

- Ensure all inputs are converted to float.
- Store the result of the list comprehension into a variable `prices`.
- Filter out anything above `dollar` and replace each of those with `1`.
- Sum all the `1`s together.

Comment: Clean, more Pythonic way = +1.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood few things in your code. You were right that this `[float(x) for x in prices]` line can convert each item in the list to float. However, I'll take **@KlausD**'s statement *"Your list comprehension does not do anything. You will have to store the result somewhere."* and also, what you're doing here `if prices <= dollar:` is directly comparing the `prices (list)` to `dollar (float)`.

You can add a `for loop` line before your `if statement` so each item will be iterated.

```
prices = input("enter a list of prices: ").split()
dollar = float(input("enter dollar amount: "))
print()
options = 0
for x in prices:
    if float(x) <= dollar:
        options += 1 
        print(f"you have {options} options")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted the program to do?

```
prices = input("enter a list of prices: ").split(",")
prices = [float(x) for x in prices]
dollar = float(input("enter dollar amount: "))
print()
options = 0
for price in prices:
    if price <= dollar:
        options += 1

print("You have "+str(options)+" options")
```

There were two main problems with your original program.

First, when you converted your string values to floats, you did not assign the list to a variable, so it was lost the instant Python finished the conversion.

Second, when you were comparing the list of float prices to the dollar price, you did not iterate through each item of the list individually. While it is possible to compare all elements with a single thing using a 'if x in list:' command, this command does not tally the matches and only handles equivalences, not less-than-or-equal to.

Finally, I tweaked your code so that it splits on a commas rather than on spaces, and it uses a regular print command rather than a string format. These are aesthetic choices, so I hope you will forgive the changes. There isn't anything wrong with format commands or with splitting on spaces.

I hope this helps.